# an R function that finds multiple objects along a column

Tags: r

It seems an easy question, and probably it is but I am not able to find an easy solution (it can also be a duplicate, but I can't find anything).

Suppose I have a string array:

```
objects = c("apple","banana","cranberry");
```

and I would like to extract the position of each object from a *fruit* column, in order to get the values contained in the other columns of the dataframe.

```
df = data.frame(fruits=c("banana","watermelon","orange","pineapple","apple","strawberry","pear","lemon","grapefruit","peach","apricot","cranberry"),asia=c(1,3,2,1,3,1,2,3,1,2,2,1),america=c(1,2,3,2,3,1,3,2,2,1,3,2));
```

Is there something similar to which() or grep() that can be used to retrieve the positions whitout having to use a for loop like this:

```
position = matrix(nrow=length(objects),ncol=2);
i = 1;
for(obj in objects){
    position[i,] = unlist(df[which(df$fruit==obj),-1]);
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Do you really want the positions? How do you define them? Your loop process seems to return the corresponding values from the other columns and not the positions. As @李哲源 mentioned, you can use this `df[df$fruits %in% objects,]`.

Comment: @AntoniosK yes, you're right. I edited the question. I need the positions.

Comment: ooook! I knew it was something very easy. I was reading the %in% help when you answered.
thanks to @李哲源

Comment: and to @antoniosk but I can't choose your comment as the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match`

```
df[match(objects, df$fruits), ]
#      fruits asia america
#5      apple    3       3
#1     banana    1       1
#12 cranberry    1       2
```

`match(objects, df$fruits)` returns the positions

```
# [1]  5  1 12
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get desired output by using `which` and `%in`

```
which(df$fruits%in%objects)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @李哲源 and @AntoniosK stated, you can also use `%in%` in a `which()` statement, then `rownames()`:

```
rownames(df[which(df$fruits %in% objects),])
[1] "1"  "5"  "12"
```